# filebeat and logstash event size calculation

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat, logstash-configuration, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am using filebeat to harvest logs from application and logstash for filter and transform log events and then publish them to elastic search output pipeline.

I would like to know the size of events at filebeat end as well as at logstash end.
could you please let me know how can i view or calculate it ?

Answer (score 0):

To start, make sure that your Elasticcluster is secured, when that is the case you can enable monitoring for the different parts:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/monitor-elasticsearch-cluster.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/configuring-logstash.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/monitoring.html

Comment: will monitoring provide me event size ?

Comment: I supposed that you mean by event size, the amount of events, if that is the case yes, otherwise please specify a bit more clear what you mean by event size

Comment: filter {
  ruby {
    code => 'size = event.get("message").size;
             event.set("message_size", size)'
            
  }   like wise you mentioned event count I would like to know the event size for each event . for example above code snippet can help you understand my requirement .

Comment: Using ruby in Logstash you can get that info as you specified yourself, I don't think it is possible to have it directly within a beat.

Comment: Just wondering, is there a specific reason why you want to have this info?

Comment: i am doing this to calculate dimensioning figures for logs out from my app like log event per second and log event size.